# mysql update query returning query empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have this update statement:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE loan SET  loan_reff_id='$_POST[loan_reff_id]',
commit_date='$_POST[commit_date]',app_loan_type='Tertiary Loan',
app_ln_amnt='$_POST[app_ln_amnt]', institution_name='$_POST[institution_name]',
app_course='$_POST[app_course]',course_length='$_POST[course_length]',
course_cost='$_POST[course_cost]', app_trm_pymnt='$_POST[app_trm_pymnt]',
app_intrst_rate=3
WHERE app_file_id='$_POST[app_file_id]'");
```

However wen I run the query it says query empty, what do you think might be the problem
Im using mysql and php

Comment: @MarcusAdams give a small example please? so you are saying: (example) commit_date='$_POST[commit_date]'..should be?

Comment: @user1027167 mysql send an error saying:Error: Query was empty

Comment: send an error to whom? how? which way? this very code you posted here doesn't have to send any errors.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Im am updating using a php form and when i fill out the textareas and submit the data the error is returned

Comment: Could it be there's a space between mysql_query and the brackets?

Comment: the error you are seeing returned by some other query.

Comment: execute: echo "UPDATE loan SET  loan_reff_id='$_POST[loan_reff_id]',
commit_date='$_POST[commit_date]',app_loan_type='Tertiary Loan',
app_ln_amnt='$_POST[app_ln_amnt]', institution_name='$_POST[institution_name]',
app_course='$_POST[app_course]',course_length='$_POST[course_length]',
course_cost='$_POST[course_cost]', app_trm_pymnt='$_POST[app_trm_pymnt]',
app_intrst_rate=3
WHERE app_file_id='$_POST[app_file_id]'"; for checking the sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not empty.
You are getting such an error from some other query.

According this one, to make it sane at the very least,

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
$sql = "UPDATE loan SET loan_reff_id='$_POST[loan_reff_id]',
commit_date='$_POST[commit_date]',app_loan_type='Tertiary Loan',
app_ln_amnt='$_POST[app_ln_amnt]', institution_name='$_POST[institution_name]',
app_course='$_POST[app_course]',course_length='$_POST[course_length]',
course_cost='$_POST[course_cost]', app_trm_pymnt='$_POST[app_trm_pymnt]',
app_intrst_rate=3
WHERE app_file_id='$_POST[app_file_id]'";

mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use directly $_POST values in your queries, you risk SQL injections, try using PDO.
Regarding the empty query, you must have a problem with simple/double quotes and concatenation.
Finally, are you sure you do not violate any constraint in your table ? NOT NULL, etc...

Comment: could you give a small example on PDO please or recommend a link, what exactly do you mean by simple/double quotes. and now i havnt violated any of the table constraints

Comment: <?php
$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE load SET loan_reff_id = :reff_id, commit_date = :commit_date WHERE app_file_id = :app_file_id');
$req->execute(array(
 'reff_id' => $$reffId,
 'commit_date' => $commitDate,
 'app_file_id' => $appFileId
 ));
?>

PDO will escape strings for you.
You need to activate it in you php.ini.